# How to jump from one directory to another directory and also display the present working directory on screen otherwise show the error?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

It's showing below error :

> please check the destination directory

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots if it is not necessary. In your case, you can equally post the code directly, with proper formatting of course. Your solution does not work, because you change the working directory in a child process, not in the process where you test the new working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var=( /home/divya/dir1 /home/divya/dir2 )
for dir_list in ${var[@]}
do
  cd "${dir_list}"
  test="$(pwd)"
  if [ "${dir_list}" = "${test}" ] ; then
     echo "Destination directory is ${test}"
  else
     echo "Check the destination directory"
 fi
done
```